# Converting this List of Lists to Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a class :

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        TemplateKeys = new List<int>();
    }

    public List<int> TemplateKeys { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create say 3 instances :

```
List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

Client client = new Client();
client.TemplateKeys.Add(1);
client.TemplateKeys.Add(2);
client.TemplateKeys.Add(3);
clients.Add(client);
//..
Client client1 = new Client();
client1.TemplateKeys.Add(1);
client1.TemplateKeys.Add(3);
clients.Add(client1);
//..
Client client2 = new Client();
client2.TemplateKeys.Add(2);
client2.TemplateKeys.Add(4);
clients.Add(client2);
```

Then I create a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> templatesInUse = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

So what I want to do is take the `TemplateKeys` used by the users in this `clients` List, to `Distinct()` them and them as keys of the `templatesInUse` Dictionary where the value for now will be `string.Empty`. The idea is that once I have the keys, I'm gonna query the database for the text associated to each key in the dicitionary. Then i'm gonna replace the `string.Empty` value witht he result from the database and I'll be able to use the templates for each user without having to query the database for the same template many times.

So what I've done was first to try to extract the distinct values which I managed to do like so:

```
List<int> res = clients.SelectMany(cl => cl.TemplateKeys)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToList();
```

Now I want to actually make this `LINQ` expression return the desired `Dictionary<int, string>` result. I see the `LINQ` has built in `ToDictionary()` extension method but I couldn't find a way to get my result by replacing `ToList()` with `ToDictionary()` like so :

```
templatesInUse  = clients.SelectMany(cl => cl.TemplateKeys)
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToDictionary(//tried some things here with no success);
```

So i saw that almost all examples with `ToDictionary` uses `GroupBy()` even though I don't need grouping and I would like to see solution that doesn't use it I remade my `LINQ` like so:

```
templatesInUse = clients.SelectMany(cl => cl.TemplateKeys)
                        .Distinct()
                        .GroupBy(t => t)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.ToString());
```

which works to some extenct but instead my desired `string.Empty` or just `""` value I get something strange for value which would work in theory since those values will be replaced but still I would like to get a *clean* by which I mean that after the execution of the `LINQ` query I would like to get the `TemplateKey` as my Dictionary key and empty string as my value. And as I mentioned I really wonder and would like to see a way without using `GroupBy()` is that a must when using `ToDictionary()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need grouping. Just specify the key as the number and value as `string.Empty.`

```
templatesInUse = clients.SelectMany(cl => cl.TemplateKeys).Distinct()
                 .ToDictionary(x => x, x => string.Empty);
```

Comment: Brr, thank you, exactly what I was trying to achieve the past 30mins.